# How to rename user and change associated file pathways(Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8.1, user-profiles

I would like to change my user name and at the same time change file pathways to include the new name. The reason is that the user name I am currently using contains greek letters and that is a problem for many programs...

Everything I have tried so far results in superficial changes, that is the user name changes but the file pathways remain the same. For example C:\Users\Γιάννης\Desktop. Could you please show me how I could accomplish that? I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the instructions [in this link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147545-user-profile-folder-change-user-account-folder-name.html) to do that.

Comment: I have already taken note of that link but unfortunately it takes too much for granted and I do not understand some steps.

Comment: It's easier to follow than it looks. And it's the only way to do it, either that or reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Okay. Take a look at step 3. I do not know If I have any files set to be shared. What could I do here?

Comment: If you don't know if you have any shared files, you probably don't. Open a window, click on "network" in the left pane and then select your computer in the list. If you don't see any folder or your computer in the list, then you don't have any shared files and can ignore that step.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Comment: Followed the steps and it worked! Thank you very much.